Bootstrap Navbar moves the window when collapses
All this happens on mobile screens. I have this navbar:
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark sticky-top navbar-expand-lg">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#top">
            <img src="images/id/logo.svg" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#presentacion">Presentación</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#proyectos">Proyectos</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#festivales">Festivales</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#formacion">Formación</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#hoy">Hoy en Día</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#forma_cto">Contacto</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#ubi">Ubicación</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="videos.html">Videos</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

And, in order to collapse the menu when it it's clicked, I use this jquery:
$('.nav-link, .navbar-brand').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});

The thing is, this moves down the window a number of pixels (exactly the height of the menu when is visible, that in this case, is 296 pixels). Now, I tried to add some scroll:
$('.nav-link, .navbar-brand').on('click', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 296);
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});

And, it collapses, but won't make the scrollup. Even if I exchange the lines won't work (same behavior, will collapse but won't scrollup):
$('.nav-link, .navbar-brand').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 296);
});

And, the odd thing is that if I just call the scrollTop api, the scrollup is done:
$('.nav-link, .navbar-brand').on('click', function() {
    $(window).scrollTop($(window).scrollTop() - 296);
});

How can I make the navbar collapse and the window to scrollup 296 pixels?
Thanks in advance.

The solution was to "separate" the navbar from the body, and in order to do so, I gave some padding to the body (as much as the height of the navbar), and added to the navbar the css value "position: fixed" (among other values):
body {
    padding-top: 56px;
}
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}

And the jquery remain the same (as in the begging):
$('.nav-link, .navbar-brand').on('click', function() {
    $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
});

I hope this helps someone in the future.
Cheers!!!
